# DLL injection to .net project

Tags: .net, hook, dll-injection

Is it possible to inject a DLL file into a .net process?
there is a process (maybe c# project) which is run under .net framework, and I want to inject a dll to it. I can hook it like other process, but injected dll does not work.

Comment: Is there any chance that you are injecting 32-bit dll to 64-bit process, or 64-bit dll to 32-bit process?

Comment: no, I know my process is 32bit, and also I try both 32bit and 64bit version of windows.

Comment: Have you attached the visual studio debugger and stepped through every line of code with GetLastError() in the watch window to find if there are any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Get the handle, allocate some memory on the process, write there the name of the dll and finally, create a thread that will call LoadLibraryA and load your dll.

Also, check the comments in code and refer to the “theory” part of this article whenever you feel the need to.

Dll:

```
#include<Windows.h>
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) bool WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hInstDll, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
    switch (fdwReason)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        {
            MessageBox(NULL, "Hello World!", "Dll says:", MB_OK);
        break;
        }
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            break;
        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
            break;
        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Injector:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

public class BasicInject
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(int dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

    [DllImport("kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procName);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
    static extern IntPtr VirtualAllocEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpAddress, uint dwSize, uint flAllocationType, uint flProtect);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool WriteProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, byte[] lpBuffer, uint nSize, out UIntPtr lpNumberOfBytesWritten);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr CreateRemoteThread(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpThreadAttributes, uint dwStackSize, IntPtr lpStartAddress, IntPtr lpParameter, uint dwCreationFlags, IntPtr lpThreadId);

    // privileges
    const int PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD = 0x0002;
    const int PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION = 0x0400;
    const int PROCESS_VM_OPERATION = 0x0008;
    const int PROCESS_VM_WRITE = 0x0020;
    const int PROCESS_VM_READ = 0x0010;

    // used for memory allocation
    const uint MEM_COMMIT = 0x00001000;
    const uint MEM_RESERVE = 0x00002000;
    const uint PAGE_READWRITE = 4;

    public static int Main()
    {
        // the target process - I'm using a dummy process for this
        // if you don't have one, open Task Manager and choose wisely
        Process targetProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("testApp")[0];

        // geting the handle of the process - with required privileges
        IntPtr procHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | PROCESS_VM_WRITE | PROCESS_VM_READ, false, targetProcess.Id);

        // searching for the address of LoadLibraryA and storing it in a pointer
        IntPtr loadLibraryAddr = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA");

        // name of the dll we want to inject
        string dllName = "test.dll";

        // alocating some memory on the target process - enough to store the name of the dll
        // and storing its address in a pointer
        IntPtr allocMemAddress = VirtualAllocEx(procHandle, IntPtr.Zero, (uint)((dllName.Length + 1) * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(char))), MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);

        // writing the name of the dll there
        UIntPtr bytesWritten;
        WriteProcessMemory(procHandle, allocMemAddress, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(dllName), (uint)((dllName.Length + 1) * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(char))), out bytesWritten);

        // creating a thread that will call LoadLibraryA with allocMemAddress as argument
        CreateRemoteThread(procHandle, IntPtr.Zero, 0, loadLibraryAddr, allocMemAddress, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Source: http://www.codingvision.net/miscellaneous/c-inject-a-dll-into-a-process-w-createremotethread

Comment: S.Spieker,thanks for your answer. my problem is that if the process which I want to inject the above dll is written for example in C#, the messagebox will not shown. As in this case none of the command in injector does'nt return any error, It means that there is no problme while injecting. it is a problem about the way of injection or about the way of writing dll.